# How can I track different streamlines in DIPY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, medical-imaging

I'm working on a project where i have to use DIPY to track different streamlines of the brain and show them separately, I found the code to track the Corpus Callosum on DIPY's official website. Only I couldn't understand how to make it track other parts like the Cingulum

you can find the code to track the Corpus Callosum [here](https://dipy.org/documentation/1.2.0./examples_built/tracking_introduction_eudx/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer inside the dataset files.
I'm working with the Stanford-HARDI dataset and I found a file names "label_info.txt" inside of it today with labels for each bundle of the white matter, here it is in case anyone didn't find it:

```
new label, freesurfef label, freesurfer name
1, 2, "Left-Cerebral-White-Matter"
1, 41, "Right-Cerebral-White-Matter"
1, 77, "WM-hypointensities"
1, 85, "Optic-Chiasm"
1, 1004, "ctx-lh-corpuscallosum"
1, 2004, "ctx-rh-corpuscallosum"
2, 251, "CC_Posterior"
2, 252, "CC_Mid_Posterior"
2, 253, "CC_Central"
2, 254, "CC_Mid_Anterior"
2, 255, "CC_Anterior"
3, 1032, "ctx-lh-frontalpole"
4, 1014, "ctx-lh-medialorbitofrontal"
5, 1012, "ctx-lh-lateralorbitofrontal"
6, 1019, "ctx-lh-parsorbitalis"
7, 1020, "ctx-lh-parstriangularis"
8, 1018, "ctx-lh-parsopercularis"
9, 1027, "ctx-lh-rostralmiddlefrontal"
10, 1003, "ctx-lh-caudalmiddlefrontal"
11, 1028, "ctx-lh-superiorfrontal"
12, 1024, "ctx-lh-precentral"
13, 1017, "ctx-lh-paracentral"
14, 1035, "ctx-lh-insula"
15, 1026, "ctx-lh-rostralanteriorcingulate"
16, 1002, "ctx-lh-caudalanteriorcingulate"
17, 1023, "ctx-lh-posteriorcingulate"
18, 1010, "ctx-lh-isthmuscingulate"
19, 1006, "ctx-lh-entorhinal"
20, 1007, "ctx-lh-fusiform"
21, 1016, "ctx-lh-parahippocampal"
22, 1009, "ctx-lh-inferiortemporal"
23, 1033, "ctx-lh-temporalpole"
24, 1015, "ctx-lh-middletemporal"
25, 1030, "ctx-lh-superiortemporal"
26, 1034, "ctx-lh-transversetemporal"
27, 1001, "ctx-lh-bankssts"
28, 1022, "ctx-lh-postcentral"
29, 1031, "ctx-lh-supramarginal"
30, 1008, "ctx-lh-inferiorparietal"
31, 1029, "ctx-lh-superiorparietal"
32, 1025, "ctx-lh-precuneus"
33, 1005, "ctx-lh-cuneus"
34, 1011, "ctx-lh-lateraloccipital"
35, 1021, "ctx-lh-pericalcarine"
36, 1013, "ctx-lh-lingual"
37, 11, "Left-Caudate"
**38, 12, "Left-Putamen"
**39, 13, "Left-Pallidum"
40, 9, "Left-Thalamus"
41, 10, "Left-Thalamus-Proper"
42, 17, "Left-Hippocampus"
43, 18, "Left-Amygdala"
44, 26, "Left-Accumbens-area"
**45, 28, "Left-VentralDC"
46, 2032, "ctx-rh-frontalpole"
47, 2014, "ctx-rh-medialorbitofrontal"
48, 2012, "ctx-rh-lateralorbitofrontal"
49, 2019, "ctx-rh-parsorbitalis"
50, 2020, "ctx-rh-parstriangularis"
51, 2018, "ctx-rh-parsopercularis"
52, 2027, "ctx-rh-rostralmiddlefrontal"
53, 2003, "ctx-rh-caudalmiddlefrontal"
54, 2028, "ctx-rh-superiorfrontal"
55, 2024, "ctx-rh-precentral"
56, 2017, "ctx-rh-paracentral"
57, 2035, "ctx-rh-insula"
58, 2026, "ctx-rh-rostralanteriorcingulate"
59, 2002, "ctx-rh-caudalanteriorcingulate"
60, 2023, "ctx-rh-posteriorcingulate"
61, 2010, "ctx-rh-isthmuscingulate"
62, 2006, "ctx-rh-entorhinal"
63, 2007, "ctx-rh-fusiform"
64, 2016, "ctx-rh-parahippocampal"
65, 2009, "ctx-rh-inferiortemporal"
66, 2033, "ctx-rh-temporalpole"
67, 2015, "ctx-rh-middletemporal"
68, 2030, "ctx-rh-superiortemporal"
69, 2034, "ctx-rh-transversetemporal"
70, 2001, "ctx-rh-bankssts"
71, 2022, "ctx-rh-postcentral"
72, 2031, "ctx-rh-supramarginal"
73, 2008, "ctx-rh-inferiorparietal"
74, 2029, "ctx-rh-superiorparietal"
75, 2025, "ctx-rh-precuneus"
76, 2005, "ctx-rh-cuneus"
77, 2011, "ctx-rh-lateraloccipital"
78, 2021, "ctx-rh-pericalcarine"
79, 2013, "ctx-rh-lingual"
80, 50, "Right-Caudate"
81, 51, "Right-Putamen"
82, 52, "Right-Pallidum"
83, 48, "Right-Thalamus"
84, 49, "Right-Thalamus-Proper"
85, 53, "Right-Hippocampus"
86, 54, "Right-Amygdala"
87, 58, "Right-Accumbens-area"
88, 60, "Right-VentralDC"
```